# How to format negative numbers without a sign

Tags: reporting-services

I have this value : `-5.55k`

Here is how I formatted it : `#,0,.00k`

But what I want it's even though it's a negative value, I don't want any sign, like this : `5.55k`

I don't know if it's possible, since I didn't find any way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either always return a positive number (the absolute value) using the `abs()` function or you can add a number format to be used specifically for negative values by using a semi-colon, so your custom number format would be `#,0,.00k;#,0,.00k` instead.